The equivalence relation when constructing the associated bundle
When constructing from a typical fibre $F$, an action of a Lie group $G$ on that fibre and a $G$-principal bundle $P$ over some base space $M$ the associated bundle $P[F]$, one does this by considering the manifold $P \times_{M} F$. Since we want the fibres of the new bundle to be $F$, we "divide by $G$". For this one notes that $G$ acts on $P$ by the principal action and on $F$ by the given action. This induces an equivalence relation on the product space $P \times_{M} F$ which looks like this:
$$ (g, s) \sim (h, t) \iff \exists x \in G: (g, s) = x \cdot (h,t) = (hx, x^{-1} \triangleright t).$$
What I do not understand is the following: Why do we need the product action on $P \times_{M} F$ to not only act on the group $G$, but on the fibre $F$ as well? Don't we just want to collapse all fibres over some point $p \in M$ in $P$, which are all essentially $G$ to a single point, so we can attach $F$? This is exactly accomplished by $g \sim h \iff \exists x \in G: g = hx$, since the principal action acts fibre-wise and is transitive, thus identifying all group elements over some point. Why do we need to identify points in the fibre $F$ as well?

If you only quotient out $P$, then you’ll always get the trivial bundle $M\times F$. But the associated bundle doesn’t necessarily give trivial bundles. Very roughly speaking, we want to replace each of the fibers $P_x\cong G$ by attaching $F$ instead, but while also keeping a “similar twist” (which is encoded in how $G$ acts on $F$ and also the whole quotient).

I think it’s always nice to think of the tangent bundle example:
Take $P$ to be the frame bundle $Fr(M)$ of your manifold $M$. This is a $GL(n)$ principal bundle, and if $p\in P$ with $x:=\pi(p)\in M$, then $p$ is a frame (aka basis) $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of $T_pM$. Another frame $q=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ is related by a transformation $g\in GL(n)$: Say
$$pg^{-1}= q.$$
To form the associated bundle which should end up being $TM$, we take $V = \mathbb R^n$ with the standard $GL(n)$ representation.
Now how do we specify a vector $v$ in $T_pM$? We can write it out in terms of a basis $v= v^i e_i$. Or we can just say $v$ is the column vector
$$v = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{bmatrix}_p$$
but we keep should keep in mind that we used the basis $p=(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ in order to do so. In a different basis $q$ we’d multiply the column vector above by the matrix $g$ to get the new representation of $v$.
$$v = \begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n\end{bmatrix}_q$$
where
$$\begin{bmatrix} w_1 \\ \vdots \\ w_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} & & \\ & g & \\ & & \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{bmatrix}$$
Notice the data of “a column vector and a basis” is exactly a point $(p,[v_1, \dotsm, v_n]^t)\in P\times \mathbb R^n$. The only thing is that we want to identify different column vectors if they are different representations of the same abstract vector $v$. That is, if we change frames by $g$, AND multiply the column by $g$, this should be the same object in our vector space. Hence the quotient by the relation
$$(p, [v_1, \dotsm, v_n]^t) \sim (pg^{-1},[g][v_1,\dotsm,v_n]^t)$$
